# How can I show all users except an user who is currently logged in using Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to show all users but i dont want to show the user who is logged in. This is what i tried:

```
def get_home_page_url(request):
    user = User.objects.all()
    h = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    print(h)
    # filtered_user = User.objects.filter(id=request.user).exclude(id=request.user)
    # print("ALL USERS:" + str(filtered_user))

    args = {
        'user': user,
        # 'filtered_user':
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', args)
```

I tried these but I am getting error and error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just exclude the current user

```
User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

user_obj=User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
context={
'user_obj':user_obj
}

```
return render(request,'index.html',context)
```